# Unity Как блокировать кнопку и возобновить её только после выполнения действия

Tags: unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

У меня проблема я делаю игру где нужна блокировку нужно поставить на Button при выполнения действия обратно активна Пожалуйста выручайте все перепробовал и перешуршал

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В компоненте "Button" есть поле "Interactable", когда значение равняется - true, то ты можешь взаимодействовать с кнопкой, а если равняется - false, то не можешь.